# Trying to create a data frame from a list extracted from website

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, extract

I am trying to make data frame in order to be able to reference it for further data extraction. I am stuck on how to make it exactly, my code is this:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd


source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://messageboards.webmd.com/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link"):
    print (url.a.get('href'))

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['link'],[for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link"):])
```

Comment: save to `txt` or `csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['link'],
            data=[url.a.get('href') for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link")])
```

Comment: @Data1234 Consider [accepting answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/345277) if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need pandas to clean your data, just save data to `txt` or `csv` file

```
with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
    for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link"):
        print (url.a.get('href'), file=f)
```

Comment: i do need pandas though i thought